# Why can't I run the project in XCode 4.1?

Tags: ios, xcode

I can build the project, but I can't run it. But why? Menu is disabled. Please see the screenshot.
[image: screenshot of the Product menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select Product>Edit scheme, then check that the Run action has an Executable selected.